# Doing an exact pixel drag in Xcode UITesting

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I know about the default way to drag an element:

```
let start = savingsCell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))
let finish = savingsCell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -80))
start.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: finish)
```

The problem here is that the drag continues in the `UITableView` beyond the 80 points that I specified. Is there a way to drag for exactly this amount without physics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the drag be an exact number of points by creating the end coordinate from the start coordinate, using the [coordinate(withOffset:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuicoordinate/1500913-withoffset) method on XCUICoordinate.

```
let start = savingsCell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))
let finish = start.withOffset(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -80))
start.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: finish)
```

The vector for the normalized method is relative to the size of the element, but the vector for `coordinate(withOffset:)` uses absolute point values. (not pixels - so on devices using @2x or @3x assets, this will actually be 160 pixels or 240 pixels respectively)